# How to accept alert in selenium which is coming up in a different window?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

Scenario: There are 2 windows open. When I am clicking a button on the 2nd window, a 3rd window is opening and the focus is automatically shifting to 3rd window. An alert is coming on the 3rd window to accept.

Issue: I am not able to accept the alert as it's coming in a different window.

Findings: I think it's the limitation of Selenium. If the alert is coming on the same window where the button is clicked, we have the DOM, so we are able to interact with the alert. But in this case the alert is in a different window, so the state of the browser is locked.

Tried solution: Tried all the possible ways by using javascript, selenium action class etc, but it's not working.

some of the tried methods are as below

```
//e.click();
                        /*Actions ac = new Actions(driver);

                        ac.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();*/
                        String onClickScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('click', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject){ arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');}";
                        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                        jse.executeScript(onClickScript, e);

                    /*  Actions asd = new Actions(driver);
                        asd.clickAndHold(e).perform();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        asd.release().perform();*/
```

Comment: you will need to switch to 3rd window before clicking on alert. you can use selenium [switch to window method](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/)

Comment: You can't perform any operation on browser as the alert is still open. The browser is in locked state and the control is not coming out of the clik event.

Comment: you are not performing any action on the browser itself. With switch method you are asking Selenium to use new window where you want to click on alert. Try it first and let me know if its not working for you.

Comment: These are the basic thing..which I have tried obviously.

Comment: You haven't mentioned anywhere about these 'obvious' basic things so that's why I asked you to try. Anyways, you can try the answer from New contributor and good luck finding your solution.

Comment: Let me explain again
 e.click(); //here we are clicking the button where alert is generated
 System.out.println("Some comment"); 
 driver.switchTo().window("WindowName"); or any other code
 
 So what is happening here is the control is not even coming out of e.click().
 The next line it should print as "Some comment" before trying to switch window or other other code. 
 Its waiting for around 10 mins and failing with the message "[1537471356.619][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000"

Comment: so I understand clicking on 2nd window opens a new window with alert but what happening in the 1st and 2nd window after click?

Comment: Sorry man..I didn't want to be rude. I tried the above 2 comments to be posted in 1 but it posted separately. I tried to edit it but I am not allowed to edit after 5 mins.

Comment: The 1st and 2nd window stays open. But the focus automatically shifts to the 3rd window where the alert is present. After clicking on alert there , we can work on the rest of the functionality on that page.

Comment: control not coming out of e.click() means webdriver is waiting for page load to complete in window 2. Is it possible you can give the site where its happening to help you out better? But as an alternative since you are sure its throwing an exception after the click you can use `try catch block`, where you can click in try block and 'switch windows' action in catch block. This will continue with rest of the code even after the exception (again, its just a suggestion as per my understanding of the issue. For better answer I would have to look at the issue)

Answer (score 0):

To clear certain doubts an *Alert* is generated through *JavaScript* and is never a part of the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

To *accept* or *dismiss* an *Alert* you must always induce *WebDriverWait* for the *alert to be present* as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
//other code
Alert myAlert = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
//accept an alert
myAlert.accept();
//dismiss an alert
myAlert.dismiss();
```

Comment: Its not about waiting for the alert to accept. Whats happening here when I am clicking the button through element.click() method, its not coming out of that method for the next statement to be executed where I can write the code to handle the alert.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution is working fine and can be used in similar scenario.

We have to use the Robot class of java.awt package.
In the below code Alt+space+c will close any opened window. Here closing the alert.

```
public void closeAlert(String strControlName, String delayTime) {
    Robot rb;
    int timeInSec = Integer.parseInt(delayTime);
    try {
        rb = new Robot();
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); //for clicking on the button or link
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Log.info("Wait for "+timeInSec+" Secs");
        Thread.sleep(timeInSec*1000);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT); 
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT); 
        Log.info("Successfully clicked on '"+strControlName+ "' and closed the Alert");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.info("Failed click on '"+strControlName+ "' and close the Alert");
    }


}
```